# What power cord does my slide projector need, and if it does not exist can I still use my projector?

Tags: leica, projector, repair-parts

I have a Leitz Prado 66 slide projector. The power socket is oval and contains two round pins set pretty far apart. Where can I obtain a replacement power cord?

[image]

Comment: What, do people not consider slide projection photography anymore?

Comment: As it's a power cord for a slide projector, closing this seems a little nitpicky. If the question were "what power cord do I need for camera X," sourcing power cords would certainly be relevant to photography. So, I guess the real question is whether a slide projector is photography equipment.

Comment: Thank you for your re-open votes. I certainly think it classifies as "using photographic equipment" in the help center: http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also, from what I read these projectors are rare and valuable. It would be a disservice to the photo community if I had to throw it out because I did not know how to resurrect it or operate it.

Comment: @dpollitt what about spare batteries for cameras? or whether the ricoh batteries are interchangeable with the sigma dp batteries? or if I wanted to replace my projector lamp with a led? You don't consider these photography questions?

Comment: @Alex They're not really photography questions, no. They're _gear_ questions, and I sympathize strongly with dpollitt here; we have a hard time attracting and keeping a community of askers and answerers around photography itself. There's room for questions about gear, but it'd be nice if they were 20% instead of what seems like 95%.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a German DIN 49491 connector, see http://www.kalthoff-elektro.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=141&Itemid=329 and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger%C3%A4testecker#.E2.80.9EWaffeleisenstecker.E2.80.9C. They are due to their main use case also known as “Waffeleisenstecker”, “Bügeleisenstecker” or “Heißgerätestecker”. With the last term, you will find many offers on German eBay, even new connectors are sold there. Unfortunately I was not able to locate some on ebay.com, since I do not know a suitable English search term.

Comment: There are a number of companies specializing in cords and connectors. This appears to be a "high temperature inlet connector". By searching for "DIN 49491" on one such supplier I found at random, I came across [one such product](http://www.worldcordsets.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_cord.tpl&product_id=1076) — although note no price is listed.